# custom post types link hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I have to independet custom post types:

1. course
2. lesson

So one course can have many lesson and one lesson can be used in many courses. It is a m:n relation.

Now I've content that should be only visible on the lesson page, if it is viewed from a specific course.

Actually the link structure is like that:

1. Go to course: *example.org/my-first-course*
2. I see all lessons, that related to this course
3. Click on a lesson. Link structure is: *example.org/great-lesson*

My problem at this stage is, that I don't know from which course the lesson i called.

One thing I can do is to attach the course id as a get parameter to the link:
*example.org/great-lesson/?course_id=123*

But I would like to have a link structure more like that:
*example.org/my-first-course/great-lesson*

How can I do this?

**.:: UPDATE: SOLUTION ::.**

Here is my solution, maybe it'll help someone.

If you use "add_rewrite_rule", don't forget to change the slug (slug-custom-post-type) for your custom post type and the query var (cpt-query-var) of it.

I've tried to use `index.php?name=$matches[1]`, but it will redirect to the custom post type and all other information in the URL will be lost. So it is important to use the custom post type query var instead.

To access the 'course' you have to use the [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) function:
`echo get_query_var('course', '');`

```
function my_rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^slug-custom-post-type/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?cpt-query-var=$matches[1]&course=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}

add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_rules');

function my_query_vars($qvars) {
  $qvars[] = 'course';
  return $qvars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use,

```
example.org/great-lesson/my-first-course
```

instead of using

```
example.org/my-first-course/great-lesson
```

as the `great-lesson` will be static here and the `id` or `slug` is dynamic which shows detailed course/lesson.

And to add custom rewrite rule you can use,

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^great_lesson/(.*)', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Then get the `slug` from url and write code according to it. Read more about [add_custom_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Comment: Thank you Rohan! I'll check the Rewrite API.

But if I'll do it like in your example, I've do add a rewrite rule to each lesson. There are over 700 lessons ...

Comment: So you can use lesson as static and try regex `^lesson/([^/]*)/([^/]*)` and pass it on `index.php?page_id=1&lesson=$matches[1]&course=$mathes[2]` when browsing a course. And if you are browsing only the lesson remove the second parameter.